# Angular Pagination: When records are deleted from first page, the records from the next page are not automatically getting refilled in the first page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pagination

I have used angular pagination to display records. I have a button 'Assign to me' for every record. When I click on this button, that particular record gets removed from the list. The problem here is, I am displaying 10 records per page. So when say, I click 'Assign to me' for 3 records, all these 3 records get removed. Ideally, the first page should pull 3 records from the second page and fill up the spaces of the 3 records that got removed from list. But this is not happening. Instead, only 7 records get displayed and the removed 3 records' space is filled with an empty space. Here is the code.

```
//Pagination Settings
$scope.quoteCurrentPage = 1;
$scope.quoteTotalItems = 834;
$scope.maxSize = 5;
$scope.itemsPerPage = 10;

//HTML
<uib-pagination total-items="quoteTotalItems" ng-model="quoteCurrentPage" max-size="maxSize" class="pagination-sm" items-per-page="itemsPerPage" boundary-links="true" rotate="true"></uib-pagination>

<div class="panel-body" ng-repeat="quote in quotes.slice(((quoteCurrentPage-1)*itemsPerPage), ((quoteCurrentPage)*itemsPerPage))">
........
</div>
```

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0):

Use `splice` for removing item from array. Try it:

```
$scope.removeQuote = function(quote) { 
   var index = $scope.qoute.indexOf(quote);
   $scope.quotes.splice(index, 1);     
}
```